# Cannot open include file: 'graphics.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, bgi

I am using `#include "graphics.h"` in c++.

I am using visual studio 2008 as my IDE.

The problem is I can't build my code.

Here is my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include "graphics.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dos.h>

char game[3][3];
void screen(void);
void introducing(void);
void input(void);
void circle(int,int);
void cross(int,int);

void main(void)
{
int gd=DETECT, gm, errorcode;   /* request auto detection */
char msg[80];
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"\\tc\\bgi"); /* initialize graphics */
errorcode = graphresult();      /* read result of initialization */
if(errorcode != grOk)
{
printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
printf("Press any key to halt:");
getch();
exit(1);
}
cleardevice();
introducing();
getche();
cleardevice();
screen();
getche();
closegraph();
}


void introducing(void)                   /*introduction of the project*/
{
    setbkcolor(5);
    int loop;
    setcolor(1);
    int r,c;
    settextstyle(5,0,3);
    outtextxy(250,200,"Loading...");
    rectangle(90,140,510,180);
for(r=0;r<100;r++)
{
for(c=0;c<100;c++)
{
bar(100+c,150,400+c,170);              /*loading bar*/
delay(100);
}
break;
}
cleardevice();
settextstyle(7,0,4);
outtextxy(20,150,"We present you the game tic tac toe!");
delay(2100);
for (loop=0; loop<500; loop++)
{
setcolor(11);
settextstyle(3,0,1);
outtextxy(640-(loop+130),10,"IN THE NAME OF ALLAH, THE MOST GRACIOUS AND THE MOST MERCIFUL!");            /*text moving from right to left*/
settextstyle(7,0,3);
outtextxy(30,300+(loop-300),"Made by:Urooj Sohail & Taleaa Ghori");                                       /*text moving from top to bottom*/
cleardevice();
}
settextstyle(3,0,1);
outtextxy(640-(500+130),10,"IN THE NAME OF ALLAH, THE MOST GRACIOUS AND THE MOST MERCIFUL!");
settextstyle(7,0,3);
outtextxy(30,400,"Made by:Urooj Sohail & Taleaa Ghori");
se ttextstyle(7,0,4);
setcolor(4);
outtextxy(10,100,"Welcome! YOU(X) v/s COMPUTER(0)");
outtextxy(200,150,"Press Enter");
}


void screen(void)               /*game board*/
{
setbkcolor(9);
{
settextstyle(5,0,8);
outtextxy(70,300,"Tic Tac Toe");
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       setfillstyle(13,4);
bar(200,120,410,330);                   /*setting the background of the board*/
int row,col;
for(row=0;row<=200;row=row+70)
{
for(col=0;col<=200;col=col+70)
{
setcolor(0);
rectangle(200+col,120+row,270+col,190+row);        /*drawing the board of 9 boxes*/
}
}
input();                        /*taking input through function*/
}

void input()
{
int x,y;
printf("Enter X co-ordinate -- ");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("Enter Y co-ordinate -- ");
scanf("%d",&y);
}
/*
for(int x=0;x<=2;x++)
{
for(int y=0;y<=2;y++)
{
if(game[x][y]=='X')
cross(x,y);
if(game[x][y]=='O')
circle(x,y);
}
}

if(game[x-1][y-1]=='*')
game[x-1][y-1]='X';
/*if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][0])          /*drawing circle
circle(235,155,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][1])
circle(305,155,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][2])             /*till 1st row
circle(375,155,20);

if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][0])
circle(235,225,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][1])
circle(305,225,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][2])
circle(375,225,20);                         /*till 2nd row

if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][0])
circle(235,295,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][1])
circle(305,295,20);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][2])             /*till 3rd row
circle(375,295,20);


if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][0])              /*drawing cross
line(215,135,255,175);
line(255,135,215,175);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][1])
line(285,135,325,175);
line(325,135,285,175);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[0][2])
line(355,135,395,175);                      /*till 1st row*
line(395,135,355,175);

if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][0])
line(215,205,255,245);
line(255,205,215,245);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][1])
line(285,205,325,245);
line(325,205,285,245);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[1][2])
line(355,205,395,245);                      /*till 2nd row*
line(395,205,355,245);

if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][0])
line(215,275,255,315);
line(255,275,215,315);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][1])
line(285,275,325,315);
line(325,275,285,315);
if(game[x-1][y-1]==game[2][2])               *till 3rd row*
line(355,275,395,315);
line(395,275,355,315);
}
*/
```

Comment: Where's the `#include "graphics.h"`?

Comment: The title and the text don;t agree - hwta exactly is the name of the file + it is not in the code sample

Comment: What is graphics.h? If it is the ancient header from DOS days, forget it, you will not be able to use it on Windows.

Comment: sorry for inconvienence mates!! it was my mistake! i copied an edited version of code befor... now i have edited my code. sorry

Comment: Wait, that's C++? And what the hell is that `void main` doing there?

Comment: yeah! @ etienne.. what if i declare my main function before! ?

Comment: Where did you find this code?  It is not. going. to. work. with Visual Studio in any way/shape/form; it uses a bunch of nonstandard header files from old Borland compilers.  Changing the order of functions doesn't matter -- graphics.h, conio.h, etc. do not exist and will not exist.

Comment: yeah that is what i told my brother who was struggling! thanx joe

Comment: is this code able to run on turbo c?

Answer (score 8):

Those functions and header are part of the old Borland graphics extensions and are not part of the standard C library or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

with `#include "graphics.h"` you include a header file of a library into your code. The header file must be in the include paths of visual studio. You can set additional include paths in the project propert within VS 2008.

To do so: right click on Project in the project explorer 
->Properties
->Additional Include directories

Comment: This should be the directory tree on the left or right side of the screen. Alternatively you can access the project properties page with the menu toolbar under "Project->Properties"

Answer (score 4):

Are you by chance trying to use the features from the Borland Graphics Interface for 16-bit DOS applications?

http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/graphics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See on this resurce:
[http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/)

There are projects with WinBGIm Graphics Library for  visual studio 2005/2008/2010